# Shrinkwrap for table-like listview not working?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a table-like listview (Im not using datatable or table because I want animations for adding items)

here is what I have come up with:

```
Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
      LimitedBox(
        maxHeight: 200.0,
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            LimitedBox(
              maxWidth: 1000,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 3,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Text('aaaaaaaaa$index'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Text('aaaaaaaaa$index'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Text('aaaaaaaaa$index'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Text('aaaaaaaaa$index'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Text('aaaaaaaaa$index'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Text('aaaaaaaaa$index'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Text('aaaaaaaaa$index'),
                          ],
                        ));
                  }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ]);
```

it came out like this:

[image]

you notice theres extra space at the bottom and the right side, I tried using shrinkwrap to get rid of that but clearly it didnt work. Does anyone know a solution to those?

Comment: maxWidth: 1000 you have given fix width

Comment: LimitedBox only works when its unconstrained, which is not the case for the outer one. Not sure why the inner one doesn't seem to work. But nesting Listviews like that also seems like a strange construction, but I also don't know how to get the required behaviour

Comment: I d not want to give it a maxWidth because I want it to shrink but it will casue hasSzie error if I dont give it a constrained size

Comment: and @IvoBeckers I want to make a table on mobile, the thing is sometimes there would be way too many columns and I have to move it outside the screen, so I thought making it scroll should work.

Comment: I found out if Im using Columns instead of ListView.builder it will work very well..